# Getting Runtime error in codejam but works fine elsewhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, error-handling, google-code

I wrote my code in python 3. It works perfectly fine on the python ide and programiz online ide but gives  **RUNTIME error** on the google platform. can someone help out as to why this is happening?
Here's the **link** to the problem:[Vestigium](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd27/000000000020993c)

```
def main(x,n,N):
n = len(x)
r = 0
for i in x:
    if len(i)> len(set(i)):
        r += 1
cols = []
k = 0
for i in range(n):
    col = []
    for j in range(n):
        col.append(x[i][j])
        if i == j:
            k += int(x[i][j])
    cols.append(col)
c = 0
for i in cols:
    if len(i)> len(set(i)):
        c += 1
print("Case #",N,":",k,r,c,)


  
 N = int(input())
    for i in range(N):
        x = []
        n = int(input())
        for j in range(n):
            row = []
            for p in range(n):
                v = int(input())
                row.append(v)
            x.append(row)
        num = i + 1
        main(x,n,num)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're handling the inputs incorrectly. You call `input()` for each element of a row, which gives an error. You're supposed to handle the entire line as one input. Replace

```
for j in range(n):
       row = []
       for p in range(n)
             v = int(input())
             row.append(v)
       x.append(row)
```

With

```
for j in range(n):
        row = list(map(int, input().split()))
        x.append(row)
```

2. Try running this statement in an IDE:

```py
print("Case #",1,":",1)
```

This prints `Case # 1 : 1`. The program clearly specifies the output to be in `Case #1: 1` format. The extra space between `#` and case number causes an error. Using Python 3 and above, use an f-string to make it easier.

```py
print(f"Case #{N}: {k} {r} {c}")
```

This should fix the Runtime Error. I still suspect it will give a wrong answer though.